# What is the technique to color code a bar chart in Microsoft Excel based on a binary value?

Tags: excel, colors, binary, bar-chart, spreadsheet

Here is my data set:

```
JAMES       3.32    M
JOHN        3.27    M
ROBERT      3.14    M
MICHAEL     2.63    M
MARY        2.63    F
WILLIAM     2.45    M
DAVID       2.36    M
RICHARD     1.70    M
CHARLES     1.52    M
JOSEPH      1.40    M
THOMAS      1.38    M
PATRICIA    1.07    F
LINDA       1.04    F
BARBARA     0.98    F
ELIZABETH   0.94    F
JENNIFER    0.93    F
MARIA       0.83    F
SUSAN       0.79    F
MARGARET    0.77    F
DOROTHY     0.73    F
```

I simply need the bar chart to show a pink bar when the sex is female and a blue bar when it is male. I've seen a lot of tutorials online regarding ranges (e.g. 1-10, 11-20, etc.) but nothing found when it comes to coloring bars based on a binary value.

Also, when selecting all 3 columns in excel, the chart in Excel only graphs Dorothy (bottom row), and labels her a "M" which is not correct:

[image]

Thanks for any who can help!

Answer (score 1):

I based this off of this guide but I'll detail how it works here on SO as well.

https://excel-example.com/charts/conditional-formatting-in-column-bar-charts

First thing to do is to reformat your data so that the table looks like this

```
Name     M      F
James    3.32    
John     3.27
Robert   3.14
Michael  2.63
Mary            2.63
William  2.45
David    2.36
Richard  1.7
Charles  1.52
Joseph   1.4
Thomas   1.38
Patricia        1.07
Linda           1.04
Barbara         0.98
Elizabeth       0.94
Jennifer        0.93
Maria           0.83
Susan           0.79
Margaret        0.77
Dorothy         0.73
```

The cells in the M column have the following formula which references the name.

```
=IF(A2="M",C2,"")
```

The cells in the F column have the following formula which references the name as well.

```
=IF(A2="F",C2,"")
```

Then you'll just highlight your new data set and insert a stacked bar chart. Hope this helps.

[image: Stacked bar chart]

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed!